# No condensation coming from my ac

Tags: air-conditioning

It's humid out yet there's no condensation coming from my ac. Thermostat set at 78 and that's what temp is inside.

Comment: What's the humidity inside?  How often does your unit kick in?

Answer (score 2):

If your unit is producing cool air, the evaporator is probably working. The condensation usually falls into a drip pan located under the evaporator heat exchanger. The drip pan drain can become clogged, which will drop the water into the air handler and from there, gravity takes over. Gravity started it, but once it's out of the pan, it's anywhere.

Start with locating the drip pan and checking the drain. You may have to sop up the condensation from the pan with sponges, towels, absorbent cats, etc. You can check with a stiff wire to see that the drain is clear.

The exit for the drain can become clogged. My drain dripped onto weeds which grew upward into the PVC pipe, allowing slime to grow into the pipe. It became a plug which had to be removed using a shop vac (wet/dry vac). Once removed, I was able to open the top of the entry point and add some diluted chlorine bleach, repeated on a regular schedule.

I also re-configured the drain to enable it to drip into a section of large diameter PVC filled with pea gravel, reducing the growth in the future.

[Newcomb and company](https://newcombandcompany.com/resources/ac-drain-line-clogged-heres-what-do) has a useful set of instructions similar to mine above.

[image: air conditioner drain diagram]

Comment: "absorbent *cats*" ... ? I'm not sure any of my cats would agree to this plan ...